# How to insert records from multiple rows and columns

Tags: php

Pls guys I'm having a difficult time figuring this out. I have a page which allows record of students to be entered based on the number of students in that class. I can't just create a form with 30 fields(test1,test2...) for a column and another for the next column. So I created a loop. But the results isn't pleasant...instead of getting the. records fitting into the respective rows and columns, it goes like this..

---

```
Id|Name|test1|test2|exam|total|
1 | a.       |15      |0       |0        |0   
2 | a.       |0       |20      |0        |0   
3 | a.       |0       |0       |50       |0   
4 | a.       |0       |0       |0        |85
```

...but I was expecting this

---

```
Id|Name|test1|test2|exam|total|
1  | a       |15     |20     |50     |85
```

So on ...
How can I achieve this please

This is the code

```
   <?php
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])))
    {
    if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
    {
    $stu_Itest = $_POST['Itest'];
    $stu_IItest = $_POST['IItest'];
    $stu_exam = $_POST['exam'];
    }
    else
    {
    $stu_Itest = $_POST['Itest'];
    $stu_IItest = $_POST['IItest'];
    $stu_exam = $_POST['exam'];
    }

    if ($_POST['Itest']) {
    //Loop through added Itest Scores
    foreach ( $_POST['Itest'] as $key=>$value ) {
    //Insert into test1_score table
    $sql_test1 = sprintf("INSERT INTO Test1_Score(Ts1_Score) VALUES ('%s')",
           mysql_real_escape_string($value) );  
    $result_test1 = mysql_query($sql_test1,$conn );
     }
     }
    if ($_POST['IItest']) {
    //Loop through added Itest Scores
     foreach ( $_POST['IItest'] as $key=>$value ) {
    //Insert into test2_score table
     $sql_test2 = sprintf("INSERT INTO Test2_Score(Ts2_Score) VALUES ('%s')",
           mysql_real_escape_string($value) );  
    $result_test2 = mysql_query($sql_test2,$conn );
    }
    }
    if ($_POST['exam']) {
    //Loop through added Exam Scores
    foreach ( $_POST['exam'] as $key=>$value ) {
    //Insert into test1_score table
    $sql_exam = sprintf("INSERT INTO Exam_Score(exam_Score) VALUES ('%s')",
           mysql_real_escape_string($value) );  
    $result_exam = mysql_query($sql_exam,$conn ));
    }
    } 

    }
    ?>
```

This is the html code

```
    <?php
    $rlt = 'SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM students';
    $rltval = mysql_query( $rlt, $conn );
    //fetchtheresults/convertresultsintoanarray 
    define('COLS',3);//numberofcolumns
    $col=0;//jjj
    if(!$rltval)
    { 
     die('Could not get data: ' .mysql_error());
     }
     echo'<table width="100" bgcolor="#ffffff"  cellspacing="0".    cellpadding="5">
     <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Test1</th><th>Test2</th><th>Exam</th><th>Total</th></tr>';
      //startfirstrow
     while($rows= mysql_fetch_array($rltval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
     {$col++;
     echo"<tr><td>
      ".$rows["id"]."</td><td>
      ".$rows["first_name"]."..".$rows["last_name"]."</td><td>
      <div><input type='text' name='Itest[]' placeholder='00'></div></td><td>
      <div><input type='text' name='IItest[]' placeholder='00'></div></td><td>
      <div><input type='text' name='exam[]' placeholder='00'></div></td><td>
      <div><input type='text' name='Total[]' placeholder='00'></div></td><td>
      </td></tr>";
     if ($col=='COLS')//havefilledthelastrow
     {$col=0;
     echo'</tr><tr>';//startanewone
     }
     }
     echo'</tr>';//endlastrow
     echo"</table>";
     ?>
```

Comment: Where is your code...

Comment: Have editted the question .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are inserting a new row of data for every test that is submitted. You need to add a check that says if a username already exists, update the test for that record instead of creating a new row.

Comment: Pls I tried the update thing but it didn't work out fine, can show me how it's done. Thanks